# Keyboard events In JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a small game where there is a fortune wheel. When the spacebar is pressed, the randomizers will start, and the results will be revealed.

Would something like this work?

```
if (keyCode == 32) {
//Does Something
}
```

I know there are other posts everywhere on the internet where they do that, but they mainly use `jQuery` (which I don't know) or they use complex JavaScript and I'm only a beginner programmer, so please bear with me if there is an obvious solution.

Comment: Add a key event listener and check the keycode.

Comment: Can you show me an example

Comment: @CoderGamer There are [plenty of examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Example). You’re not looking for `keyCode`, by the way, but for `code` or `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`charCode` is deprecated, but you could use the `key` property instead. Something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  if (e.key === ' ') {
    console.log('start the randomizers');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
element.addEventListener("keypress(or whatever event)", () => {
  //Do something
})
```

You attach eventlistener to key being pressed. You can go to w3c to look up adding event listeners and you can also google a list for all js events. You have keeypress keyup etc. You can have your logic for whatever transpires after the event has occured in one function and just call it in the event listener. You can call multiple functions setting off a chain of events.

Comment: I just added to my comment above